# How to create and animate an uneven hamburger button into an X button with CSS only?

Tags: css, button, icons, hamburger-menu

I want to create an uneven hamburger button like this:

[image]

and transform/animate it into an X button, on click:

[image]

Of course, with CSS only.
How to do it? (maybe a trivial question but I am far from a CSS expert)

Comment: Try and do it yourself first. Look into SVG shapes and CSS Keyframes.

Comment: So how did you create the "uneven hamburger," is it an `<img>`, `<svg>`, a series of elements...? Please share your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code, we're unlikely to write all the code for you, but if you show your starting point and your best attempt(s), we may be able to help iron out your mistakes, or show you better approaches.

Comment: Excuse but I have nothing to share as I don't know how to do this. As already said: I am not an css expert. I need a full example to start from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
  width: 9px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
  width: 12px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">CSS Nav</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I'm looking for. I was asking for an uneven hamburger button (see pic). In your example there is a standard/normal hamburger.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rizeen, this is it! One minor issue is that the "x" is a bit deformed.  If you can adjust it...

Comment: Done! Hope this is what you need.